# Is there any lower layer object manipulation function than "marshal" or "cPickle" in Python?

Tags: python, c

For example, Marshal is still parsing the input data, according to Python source.

```
.....
case TYPE_FALSE:
    Py_INCREF(Py_False);
    retval = Py_False;
    break;

case TYPE_TRUE:
    Py_INCREF(Py_True);
    retval = Py_True;
    break;

case TYPE_INT:
    retval = PyInt_FromLong(r_long(p));
    break;

case TYPE_INT64:
    retval = r_long64(p);
    break;

case TYPE_LONG:
    retval = r_PyLong(p);
    break;

case TYPE_FLOAT:
.......
```

Is there any lower layer object manipulation function than "marshal" or "cPickle" in Python?

For example, I already loaded the dumped data to memory, which I just want to type casting like we can do in C/C++, `(PyObject *) data_loaded_in_memory;`

**Edit**: If this cannot be done in python directly, any hints about C functions to write that ability would be great.

Comment: Can you clarify how the data can be in memory, but not be a Python object, or a Pickle object, etc?

Comment: @agf, It could be a pickle object, marshal object or something more raw dumps that could directly type castable to PyObject or kind of. data can be loaded to memory directly by another C function.

Comment: I don't think you could just take the memory image of python object, store it, load it back in different interpreter or even the same one later and expect it to make sense. It will not. In another words, `cPickle` is the lowest possible layer (`CPickle` is lower level than `marshal`, because the later maintains compatibility between versions and platforms, which `cPickle` does not).

Comment: @Jan, I think that's the answer to my question, I would happy to accept it if you put it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think you could just take the memory image of python object, store it, load it back in different interpreter or even the same one later and expect it to make sense. It will not. Integers and floats may be fully contained in the object structure, but string already has a separately-allocated buffer for the data and even a long does.

In another words, `cPickle` is the lowest possible layer (`cPickle` is lower level than `marshal`, because the later maintains compatibility between versions and platforms, which cPickle does not) allowing to store the objects and load them in another interpreter or the same interpreter if they were released from memory in between.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not really need to serialize Python objects in general, only encode and decode certain specific things, then you might look at the [`struct` module](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7.1/library/struct.html).  This module would be used to work directly with byte-strings that represent C structs (example: DNS protocol packets).  Similar idea to `pack` and `unpack` in Perl.